Custom glyphs for visualizing threads in Gnus summary buffer not working in all backends
in the Gnus summary buffer I customized the threading appearance:
(setq-default
   gnus-sum-thread-tree-leaf-with-other "├── "
   gnus-sum-thread-tree-single-leaf "└── "
   gnus-sum-thread-tree-vertical "│ ")

When I'm reading my mail or mailing lists like emacs-devel via news.gmane.io it works as expected.
Expected behaviour looks something like this as opposed to the default behaviour.
Unfortunately I can't get this to work in nnhackernews and nnreddit.
There threads just get indented by whitespace.
Does anyone how what I am missing here?

Maybe these buffers are unibyte or the coding system they use is not UTF-8?

nnhackernews does set its own parameters for gnus-summary-line-format, see here.
It should work as intended if you change this to your default format string.
